# hide label and also its height in UiView in xamarin(iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I am working on some feature in my Application. but I am in stack at here.

I want to hide the Label and set it height constraint to 0.so that it's height is not occupy in the View if the Label is hidden.

I do google many thing but nothing is help be.

What I try is :

1. Hide the label using below code.

   `lbl_check.Hidden = true;`

but i can't set the label height to 0. 
How to set the height to 0.

I am new in Xamarin ios so if this is small issue then forgive me.

Any help be Appreciated.

Comment: try self.lbl_check.constant = 0;

Comment: @TusharSharma their is no property `self.lbl_check.constant = 0;` in xamarin ios

Comment: you have to take height constraint IBOutlet connection in your controller as well and then try this .

Comment: In xamarin their is not Outlet you can direct access the label.

Comment: i do not know about xamarin sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take hight constraint as property in your code, then you have to set that constraint.constant = 0
Hope this will help.

Comment: Ya but my label is multiline so that i am give constraint to `Top, Bottom, Left, and Right`.

Comment: yes that not work. i can't write constant is give me error.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Frame to zero...

```
someLabel.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or remove it from the SuperView and add it back later...

```
someLabel.RemoveFromSuperview();
```

Comment: @SushilHangover and if i want to add that label same place after later then how to add that lable at the same place.

Comment: @Ironman That really depends upon how you are adding it in the first place, personally I do not use Storyboard/xibs and thus is it easy to re-add as I have the UI/constaints/etc.. in code...  otherwise you would need to recreate the constraints in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the label's text to be an empty string "" & setting the label's hidden property to be true. I haven't used xamarin before, but I've run across this in UIKit using swift.